# Graph with two edge-disjoint Hamiltonian paths between the same vertex-pair

Tags: extremal-graph-theory, hamiltonian-paths

Provided existence, what is the smallest graph $G(V,E)$ with two edge-disjoint Hamiltonian paths between $u$ and $v;\ \lbrace u,v\rbrace\subset V$?

Comment: I guess you want to exclude the graph with a unique vertex. In this case the minimal number of vertices is 5 ($K_5$ has two edge-disjoint hamiltonian cycles). It's easy to check that 4 or less is impossible.

Comment: 5 doesn't suffice; let the first path be A,B,C,D,E then every other Hamilton path between A and E shares an edge with the first one: A,C,D,B,E: (C,D); A,D,B,C,E:(B,C); A,D,C,B,E: (C,D),(B,C); A,C,B,D,E: (BC); A,B,D,C,E: (AB).  However 6 vertices are sufficient A,B,C,D,E,F and A,C,E,B,D,F.

Comment: I see, I thought you authorized $u=v$

Comment: If you add edges to the smallest solution you preserve hamiltonicity and end with K_n, right?

Comment: @joro of course adding edges preserves Hamiltonian paths and cycles; a subset relation $A\subseteq B$ remains true when adding elements to $B$; is that interesting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Juust to indicate that there is a solution to the problem:
the trivial solution for the smallest graph with $k$ edge-disjoint Hamilton paths between a given pair of vertices is to take a graph $G'$ with $k$ edge-disjoint Hamilton cycles and split one of its vertices.

The smallest graph with two edge-disjoint Hamilton cycles is $K_5$ and so the smallest graph that solves the original problem is a vertex-split $K_5$ depicted below:

[image]